# Compare date filed with month and year in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date field in one of my tables and the column name is `from_dt`. Now I have to compare a month and year combination against this `from_dt` field and check whether the month has already passed. The current database function uses separate conditions for the month and the year, but this is wrong as it will compare month and year separately. The current code is like this

```
SELECT bill_rate, currency FROM table_name WHERE 
emp_id = employee_id_param
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM from_dt) <= month_param
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM from_dt) <= year_param
```

Now the `fromt_dt` field has value `2021-10-11`. If I give `month_param` as `01` and `year_param` as `2022`, this condition will not work as the month 10 is greater than 1, which I have given. Basically, I need to check whether `01-2022` (Jan 2022) is greater than r equal to `2021-10-01`(October 1st, 2021). It would be very much helpful if someone can shed some light here.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check whether one date is `>=` then another:

```
# select '2022-01-01'::date >= '2021-10-11'::date;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

If you want to restrict to year/month then:

```
select date_trunc('month','2022-01-01'::date) >= date_trunc('month', '2021-10-11'::date);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Where the `date_trunc` components are:

```
select date_trunc('month','2022-01-01'::date) ;
  date_trunc       
------------------------
 2022-01-01 00:00:00-08

 select date_trunc('month','2021-10-11'::date) ;
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2021-10-01 00:00:00-07
```

See [Postgres date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the given `year_param` and `month_param` are integers you can use the `make_date` function to create the first of the year_month and `date_trunc` to get the first on the month from the table. Just compare those values. (See [date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html)) So:

```
select bill_rate, currency 
  from table_name  
 where emp_id = employee_id_param 
   and date_trunc('month',from_dt) = 
       make_date( year_param, month_param, 01);
```